# What if beautifulsoups call returns null?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
pagelinks = myhtml.findAll('a')

for link in pagelinks:
   do_stuff()
```

If pagelinks is null, will this error out?

How can I make pagelinks a collection of 0 items in case it is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findAll`  returns an empty list `[]` when nothing matches

```
for link in pagelinks:
    do_stuff()  # never executed when findAll returns []
```